# How can I build a Mac OS X .app from an eclipse program

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, slick2d

My program works fine in Eclipse. However, if I try to export it as a runnable jar, the jar doesn't open when I double click it. Is there a way, in Eclipse, to export directly to a .app?

Comment: Is the problem that you need a program you can run by double clicking or do you need a .app? If you get the .jar to run, is that a satisfying solution?

Comment: Actually, by now, I realized why making a .jar didn't work for me. I had in Eclipse my data folder outside of src. So now, whenever I try and run a jar, the data folder has to be in the same directory as the .jar

Answer (score 5):

The [gradle-macappbundle plugin](https://github.com/crotwell/gradle-macappbundle) is the easiest way I know how to do this. It hooks into your build system and generates the `.app` for you.

---

If you want to roll your own solution, Apple’s [Java Deployment Options for OS X](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Java/Conceptual/Java14Development/03-JavaDeployment/JavaDeployment.html) gives you all the information you need to know about doing this. Basically a `.app` is just a folder containing a JAR, with some XML files giving the classpath and so on. You can read that guide for all the details.

Answer (score 0):

No. Apps contain a lot of other stuff. If you want the jar to run, you have to setup something to tell it to be opened by the JRE. Wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: Fine. How can I make a runnable Jar in Eclipse? If I try to use the default export, I get this error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: no lwjgl in java.library.path

Comment: I've been using Java on Mac for almost a decade, have never seen that. Are you building with the JRE or JDK? Which version?

Comment: Um... I don't know what those are. Also, lwjgl is a gaming library, that may be why you've never seen it?

Comment: @Impmaster you have to add LWJGL to your build path

Comment: I did that in Eclipse, and in Eclipse, it works fine. But how do I LWJGL to my build path if I've already built a jar?

Answer (score 0):

There are (at least) two separate Ant tasks that can take a JAR file and associated resources and build a `.app` bundle.  The [appbundler task](http://java.net/projects/appbundler) from java.net produces `.app` bundles that run on the Oracle Java 7 JRE and the [jarbundler task](http://informagen.com/JarBundler/) produces bundles that run on the Java 6 supplied by Apple.  But neither task will produce a `.app` that can run on both Java 6 and 7 because Oracle (7) and Apple (6) Javas use fundamentally different APIs for spawning the JVM from the launcher stub in the `.app`.  If you want to be able to release your Java app to the Mac App Store then you have to use Java 7 and embed a copy of the JRE in the `.app` bundle (which appbundler can do for you).  Conversely, if you want your app to be runnable on Mac OS X version 10.6 or earlier then you need to use Java 6.

Your comment on one of the other answers suggests that your app requires a native library.  You need to put this library inside the `.app` bundle along with your JAR.  The `.jnilib` needs to go in `Contents/Resources/Java` for a Java 6 bundle (the same place as the JAR file), for a Java 7 bundle you specify the library in the `<librarypath>` fileset and it will be copied to the right place by appbundler (`Contents/MacOS`).

Answer (score 0):

When you export you must choose Runnable Jar File and then it will run when you double click it.